# SparkJob file name

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, hql, hivecontext

I'm using a HQL query, that contains something similar to...

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE ex_tb.ex_orc_tb
select *, SUBSTR(INPUT__FILE__NAME,60,4), CONCAT_WS('-', SUBSTR(INPUT__FILE__NAME,71,4), SUBSTR(INPUT__FILE__NAME,75,2), SUBSTR(INPUT__FILE__NAME,77,2))
 from ex_db.ex_ext_tb
```

When I go into hive, and I use that command, it works fine.

When I put it into a pyspark, hivecontext command, instead I get the error...

```
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u"cannot resolve 'INPUT__FILE__NAME' given input columns: [list_name, name, day, link_params, id, template]; line 2 pos 17"
```

Any ideas why this might be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`INPUT__FILE__NAME` is a Hive specific virtual column and it is not supported in Spark.

Spark provides `input_file_name` function which should work in a similar way:

```
SELECT input_file_name() FROM df
```

but it requires Spark 2.0 or later to work correctly with PySpark.